# The dropdown sticks to the top while I want it to appear right next to the tile I am hovering over

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

l recently learned to make a navigation menu so I ventured on my own to make a dropdown. I did this all on my own and it seems I am weak in targeting the style properties. So I need some help.

[image]

Here's the code

> ```
> <style>
>         body {
>             margin: 0;
>         }
>
>         .menu {
>             width: fit-content;
>             float: left;
>         }
>
>         .under {
>             width: 100px;
>             float: left;
>             background-color: #242a38;
>             position: absolute;
>             z-index: 1;
>         }
>
>         nav ul {
>             list-style-type: none;
>             margin: 0;
>             padding: 0;
>         }
>
>         nav ul li.border {
>             text-align: center;
>             border-bottom: 1px solid white;
>             margin: 5px 5px;
>         }
>
>         nav ul li a {
>             color: #ffffff;
>             text-decoration: none;
>             font-family: Candara;
>             font-size: 14px;
>             display: block;
>             padding: 10px;
>             margin: 5px 0px;
>             z-index: 10;
>
>         }
>
>         nav ul li a:hover {
>             background-color: #4e596f;
>             transition: 1s;
>
>         }
>
>         
>
>         .hello {
>             float: left;
>         }
>
>         .text {
>             position: absolute;
>             left: 700px;
>             top: 145px;
>             font-family: segoe script;
>             color: #ffffffc4;
>             text-decoration: #1eacc5 underline;
>             font-size: 50px;
>             transform: rotate(1.5deg)
>         }
>
>         #full-span {
>             width: 100%;
>             height: 100%;
>             position: fixed;
>         }
>
>         .stretch {
>             width: 100%;
>             height: 100%;
>         }
>
>         nav ul ul{
>             width: 100%;
>             background: #242a38;
>             display: none;
>             position: absolute;
>             left: 100%;
>             top: 0;
>             z-index: 999;
>         }
>
>         ul li:hover > ul{
>             display: block;
>
>         }
>
>         ul ul li {
>             display: block;
>         }
>
>
>         nav ul ul a{
>             padding: 10px 5px;
>             margin: 5px 5px 11px 10px;
>         }
>
>
>
>     </style>
>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <div class="menu">
>         <div class="under">
>             <nav>
>                 <ul>
>                     <li class="border"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>                     <li class="border"><a href="#">About</a></li>
>                     <li class="border"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
>                     <li class="border"><a href="#">Contact</a>
>                         <ul>
>                             <li><a href="#">Local 1</a>
>                             <ul>
>                                 <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
>                                 <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
>                                 <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
>                             </ul>
>                             </li>
>                             <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
>                             <li><a href="#">Local</a>
>                             <ul>
>                                     <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
>                                     <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
>                                     <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
>                                 </ul>
>                                 </li>
>                         </ul>
>                     </li>
>                     <li class="border"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>             </nav>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </body>
> ```

I want the dropdown to appear next to the tile I am hovering over but it goes to the top.

At first the dropdown expanded right below overlapping the original menu so I tried:

`position: absolute;`
`left: 100%;`
`top: 0;`

Now it doesn't overlap but instead sticks to the top

Answer (score 0):

making your parent div ( class `border` in your case) `position: relative` will do the job. also make the child ( which will be shown after hover on `border` ) `top: 50%` and `transform: translate(0, -50%)`. this will make your child list vertically centered based on the parent element

I've commented before all the code that I've added/edited. check them out

```html
<style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .menu {
            width: fit-content;
            float: left;
        }

        .under {
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #242a38;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul li.border {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
            margin: 5px 5px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Candara;
            font-size: 14px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px 0px;
            z-index: 10;

        }

        nav ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #4e596f;
            transition: 1s;

        }

        

        .hello {
            float: left;
        }

        .text {
            position: absolute;
            left: 700px;
            top: 145px;
            font-family: segoe script;
            color: #ffffffc4;
            text-decoration: #1eacc5 underline;
            font-size: 50px;
            transform: rotate(1.5deg)
        }

        #full-span {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .stretch {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        nav ul ul{
            width: 100%;
            background: #242a38;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            
            /*  make top 50% to keep it at the middle */
            top: 50%;
            
            z-index: 999;
            
            /* add this code to perfectly center the after hover element. e.g "Local" */
            transform: translate(0, -50%)
        }

        ul li:hover > ul{
            display: block;

        }

        ul ul li {
            display: block;
        }


        nav ul ul a{
            padding: 10px 5px;
            margin: 5px 5px 11px 10px;
        }
        
        /* add position: relative to your border class. so any child of it with absolute position will be positioned relative to this */
        .border{
            position: relative;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="under">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Local 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the child ul element absolute to its relative parent li

so make the parent <li relative

```
nav li{
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .menu {
            width: fit-content;
            float: left;
        }

        .under {
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #242a38;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul li.border {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
            margin: 5px 5px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Candara;
            font-size: 14px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px 0px;
            z-index: 10;

        }

        nav ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #4e596f;
            transition: 1s;

        }

        

        .hello {
            float: left;
        }

        .text {
            position: absolute;
            left: 700px;
            top: 145px;
            font-family: segoe script;
            color: #ffffffc4;
            text-decoration: #1eacc5 underline;
            font-size: 50px;
            transform: rotate(1.5deg)
        }

        #full-span {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .stretch {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        nav li{
          position:relative;
        }
        nav ul ul{
            width: 100%;
            background: #242a38;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        ul li:hover > ul{
            display: block;

        }

        ul ul li {
            display: block;
        }


        nav ul ul a{
            padding: 10px 5px;
            margin: 5px 5px 11px 10px;
        }



    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="under">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Local 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to this quick fix with position: relative;

Only problem is that it takes space under the hovered nav item.

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .menu {
            width: fit-content;
            float: left;
        }

        .under {
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #242a38;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav ul li.border {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
            margin: 5px 5px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Candara;
            font-size: 14px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px 0px;
            z-index: 10;

        }

        nav ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #4e596f;
            transition: 1s;

        }

        

        .hello {
            float: left;
        }

        .text {
            position: absolute;
            left: 700px;
            top: 145px;
            font-family: segoe script;
            color: #ffffffc4;
            text-decoration: #1eacc5 underline;
            font-size: 50px;
            transform: rotate(1.5deg)
        }

        #full-span {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
        }

        .stretch {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        nav ul ul{
            width: 100%;
            background: #242a38;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        ul li:hover > ul{
            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }

        ul ul li {
            display: block;
        }


        nav ul ul a{
            padding: 10px 5px;
            margin: 5px 5px 11px 10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="under">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Local 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Local</a>
                            <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Okkk</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Not Ok</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Yes Ok</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="border"><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```